# Domain and subdomain site in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis

i am developing a site which demo URL is http://www.abc.com now my client wants all member pages open in a new URL like http://members.abc.com and this site is design and developed in ASP.Net with C#. I am too confused that how we can do this?
I want to maintain login status on both domains. How to manage this functionality?

Comment: Well for one, you will obviously need to create the `members` zone and set up the `A record` accordingly. You'll need to configure IIS to respond to this zone. You can point the members zone for this site to the same directory as your non members site and use some logic to determine the URL within your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the duplicate site you would need to create a new DNS A record and then set up the site in IIS. If the sites will always be exact duplicates running the same web application then you could create a [CNAME record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) which would make `members.abc.com` an alias of `www.abc.com`.

To share the cookie between the two subdomains you explicitly set the cookie domain to `abc.com`.

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("foo", "bar");
cookie.Domain = "abc.com";
```